# How to implement custom toggleSwitch in React Native?

Tags: react-native, toggle

I am implementing custom toggleSwitch in react native.I am new in react native. I gone through below link but I am not able achieve the implement.

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-toggle-switch-with-react

I also check https://dev.to/narendersaini32/how-to-create-custom-toggle-button-in-react-387m

***Login.js***

```
 import React from 'react';
import styles from './style';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Switch
} from "react-native";
class Login extends React.Component {
 

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
         </View>

          <View>
               <ToggleComponent/> //I want to import here toggleSwitch
          </View>
         
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}  

export default Login;
```

***ToggleButton.js***

```
import React from 'react';
const ToggleComponent = ({}) => (
 *****************??**************

);



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  


})

export default ToggleComponent;
```

I want to implement custom ToggleSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

import this component in your file where you want to use it.

```
import ToggleComponent from "../location_of_ToggleComponent.js"
```

and then you can use it like any other component.

```
<ToggleComponent />
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react

also refer to this for more information

Comment: thanks for the comment.  That thing is working fine. But How to implement toggle code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/toggle-switch-react-native you can use this library for toggle button. also if you are using react native version above 0.60 take a look at this https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/switch also. if you still gets stuck let me know i will post code.